Error "Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3" in useQuery with React Query and TypeScript
I am using useQuery from React Query in my React Native project to fetch live scores. I want to pass three arguments: the query key, a fetch function, and an options object. However, I am encountering an error: "Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.ts(2554)".
 const { data, error, isLoading, refetch } = useQuery(
    ['liveScores', selectedDate.date, selectedTimeZone],
    () => fetchLiveScore(selectedDate.date, selectedTimeZone),
    {
      keepPreviousData: true,
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        setFilteredMatches(data.data);
        const initialExpandState = Object.values(data.data).reduce((acc: any, item: any) => {
          acc[item[0].league.name] = true;
          return acc;
        }, {});
        setExpandCard(initialExpandState);
      },
    }
  );

I have tried to ensure that all types are correctly defined, but the error persists.
Here are the imports and state declarations:
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import fetchLiveScore from '../api/liveScores';

const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState<DateItem>({
  id: new Date().getTime(),
  date: new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]
});
const [selectedTimeZone, setSelectedTimeZone] = useState(
  Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
);
const [filteredMatches, setFilteredMatches] = useState([]);
const [expandCard, setExpandCard] = useState<{ [key: string]: boolean }>({});

This is my actual hook
useEffect(() => {
    const getLiveScores = async () => {

      try {

        if (selectedDate) {
          setLoading(true)
          const data = await fetchLiveScore(selectedDate.date, selectedTimeZone);
          setMatches(data.data);
          setFilteredMatches(data.data)
          const initialExpandState = Object.values(data.data).reduce((acc: any, item: any) => {
            acc[item[0].league.name] = true;
            return acc;
          }, {});

          setExpandCard(initialExpandState);
          setIsError(null)
          setRefreshing(false);
        }
      }
      catch (error: any) {
        console.error('Error fetching live scores:', error);
        setIsError(error)
        throw error;
      }
      finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }

    getLiveScores()
  }, [selectedDate, refreshing])

How can I correctly use useQuery with three arguments in this context? Any help would be appreciated.
What did I try?
I have double-checked the useQuery function definition and ensured that my fetch function and options object are correctly structured. I have also reviewed the React Query documentation, but I couldn't find a solution to this specific TypeScript error.
What was I expecting?
I was expecting the useQuery function to accept three arguments: a query key, a fetch function, and an options object, without any TypeScript errors.
How can I correctly use useQuery with three arguments in this context? Any help would be appreciated.

Is it really supported? I thought you can either use 2-arg shortcut or build a whole object with queryFn and queryKey among other opts and pass as the only arg. Please cite the relevant documentation that supports the 3-arg form. And also post your package.json - perhaps such format was introduced only recently and your version doesn't support it.

The signature you are describing is valid in version 3, but not in version 4 or version 5.
You are likely looking at the wrong version of the documentation.
Alternatively you might have multiple conflicting versions downloaded since version 3 is a separate project on npm: Version 3, Version >=4.
